# Pass Data To GetVaryByCustomString From A Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

I have a ASP.NET MVC application and i use output cache.

> I need to extra information from database at GetVaryByCustomString
>   method.

I can't use Session, TempData etc... at GetVaryByCustomString .

**How can i pass data to GetVaryByCustomString  from a controller?**

```
//In Controller
Session["IsAdmin"] = LoggedUser.IsAdmin;
Session["IsSalesMan"] = LoggedUser.IsSalesMan;
Session["SomeData"] = SomeObject.SomeData;

//In global.asax
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    var session = context.Session;
    var request = context.Request;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    //here throw exception becauase session is null
    sb.Append(session["IsAdmin"]);
    sb.Append(session["IsSalesMan"]);
    sb.Append(session["SomeData"]);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```